# Is the description of the "Contiguity within looping patterns " in the document correct?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

as the description in [flink CEP document](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/libs/cep/):

1. `Strict Contiguity:` Expects all matching events to appear strictly one after the other, without any non-matching events in-between.
2. `Relaxed Contiguity`: Ignores non-matching events appearing in-between the matching ones.
3. `Non-Deterministic Relaxed Contiguity`: Further relaxes contiguity, allowing additional matches that ignore some matching events.

---

first example is easy to understand:

given the pattern : `"a b"`

and the input `"a", "c", "b1", "b2"`

1. Strict Contiguity output : `{} (no match)`
2. Relaxed Contiguity output : `{a b1}`
3. Non-Deterministic Relaxed Contiguity output : `{a b1}, {a b2}`

---

but example of `Contiguity within looping patterns` is really hard to understand:

given the pattern : `"a b+ c"`.

and the input : `"a", "b1", "d1", "b2", "d2", "b3" "c"`

1. Strict Contiguity: {a b3 c}
2. Relaxed Contiguity: {a b1 c}, {a b1 b2 c}, {a b1 b2 b3 c}, {a b2 c}, {a b2 b3 c}, {a b3 c}
3. Non-Deterministic Relaxed Contiguity: {a b1 c}, {a b1 b2 c}, {a b1 b3 c}, {a b1 b2 b3 c}, {a b2 c}, {a b2 b3 c}, {a b3 c}

`the Strict Contiguity output {a b3 c}`, but this is against the description in `Strict Contiguity`, since there are many `non-matching events` between `a` and `b3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are right. With strict contiguity, it does not match at all. I wrote the following example to make sure:

```java
public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> events = env.fromElements("a", "b1", "d1", "b2", "d2", "b3", "c");

        AfterMatchSkipStrategy skipStrategy = AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent();
        Pattern<String, String> pattern =
                Pattern.<String>begin("a", skipStrategy)
                        .where(
                                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                                        return element.startsWith("a");
                                    }
                                })
                        .next("b+")
                        .where(
                                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                                        return element.startsWith("b");
                                    }
                                })
                        .oneOrMore().consecutive()
                        .next("c")
                        .where(
                                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                                        return element.startsWith("c");
                                    }
                                });

        PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(events, pattern).inProcessingTime();
        patternStream.select(new SelectSegment()).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>(true));
        env.execute();
    }

    public static class SelectSegment implements PatternSelectFunction<String, String> {
        public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) {
            return String.join("", pattern.get("a"))
                    + String.join("", pattern.get("b+"))
                    + String.join("", pattern.get("c"));
        }
    }
}
```

I've created [FLINK-27456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27456) to track this.